# How can I generate a flat excel file from a .rdl report?

Tags: .net, excel, reporting-services, rdl

I have a .rdl report that formats data as a report.  I want to export that data to excel as a flat table with the raw data that was returned based on the params in the report.  The default excel export looks just like the report which isn't what I want (I just want rows and columns).  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Save it in a CSV format?

Comment: I tried that, but when I open it in excel everything is in the A1 cell...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save it as csv file. After that you must import that file in excel not open that with excel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it as a non-CSV format then make sure that you have zero formatting on any of the report and also try and make sure that any fields are converted into their type - sometimes excel misunderestimates dates etc, Use .net convert functions to do this - alternatively you may have to hack the dataset datatype for a field.

Remove any headers, footers, charts - you're basically after as vanilla as possible

If you do include any of these, make sure they start and finish points line up, if not then you'll get split cells.